# ASP.NET How to access multiple form labels text property with foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, label, controls

I have a form runat= "server" with id = "myform" . It is a profile page with lots of labels. I am getting their input text from SQL database. But if the SQL data base have null value, then i wish their text get changed to "Not Specified". For such reason i am using following code, but it is not working.

```
foreach (Control item in myform.Controls)
{
    Label lbl = null;
    bool labelIsEmpty = false;
    try
    {
        lbl = (Label)item;
        labelIsEmpty = (lbl.Text == string.Empty && lbl != null);
    }
    catch 
    {
    }

    if (labelIsEmpty)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Not Specified";
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please define `is not working.` are you getting any error?

Comment: Not getting any errors( No YSOD i.e. Yellow Screen Of Death ) but the text property of label has default text "Label". And i want to change it from code.

Answer (score 3):

`myform.Controls` will gives you a collection that contains all controls withing the container( not only labels). So you have to check for the type for control while iterating the collection in order to avoid throwing exception. In the additional comment you ware specify that `label has default text "Label"` so you need to include this also in the condition. The whole scenario can be implemented like the following:

```
      foreach (Control  item in myform.Controls)
        {
            if (item is Label)
            {
              var  lbl = (Label)item;
              bool labelIsEmpty = false;
              try
              {
                  lbl = (Label)item;
                  labelIsEmpty = (lbl != null && lbl.Text == string.Empty && lbll.Text!="Label");
              }
              catch 
              { 
              //Throw error message
              }
              if (labelIsEmpty)
              {
                  lbl.Text = "Not Specified";
              }
            }
        }
```

Note :-

> You need to reorder the conditions to avoid exception. Check for
>   `string.Empty` should be comes after check for control is  `null`.
>   Because `AND`  will not check for second condition if first one is
>   false, `lbl.Text` will throw `NullReferenceException` if `lbl` is null

Comment: Thank You So much :) from your answer i was able to edit my code. But there are still some changes require in your answer. Like there should be Label instead of TextBox. Thanks @un-lucky

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control item in myform.Controls)
        {
            if (item is Label)
            {
                var lbl = (Label)item;
                bool labelIsEmpty = false;
                try
                {
                    lbl = (Label)item;
                    labelIsEmpty = (lbl != null && (lbl.Text == string.Empty || lbl.Text == "Label"));
                }
                catch
                {
                    //Throw error message
                }
                if (labelIsEmpty)
                {
                    lbl.Text = "Not Specified";
                }
            }
        }
```